# Selenium: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to run a simple test with Selenium that somebody over in QA setup for me. This test has run before, and passed, but now I keep getting an error message. I don't know what it means, but I don't think it's a problem with my code, I think it's a problem with Selenium. This is the error:

```
failed: System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [IP ADDRESS]
```

What does it mean? The "remote server" is actually my dev-box, so I can't think of why it couldn't connect. I've disabled my Firewall and still nothing.

Is there something simple I'm missing? Is there a config file that I need to setup?

Comment: Haha! Looking back 3 years later...it was pretty arrogant of me to say "I don't think it's a problem with my code, I think it's a problem with Selenium". :O)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have Selenium RC running. I use a simple batch file called Selenium.bat that looks like this:

```
java -jar c:\selenium\selenium-server.jar -multiwindow
```

(-multiwindow prevents [framekiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) code from breaking your test)